# How to enable dots (.) in subroutine names?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am working on creating a module with dynamic accessors, using autoloading. The called methods will have one or multiple dots in their names. Usage example:

```
use MyModule;
my $var=MyModule->a.method.get;
#MyModule::a.method.get() is now defined
```

It appears that the dots are illegal characters in subroutine names:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub mr.s
{
        print "OK\n";
}
mr.s();
```

gives out

```
Illegal declaration of subroutine main::mr at main.pl line 5
```

**So, how do I enable dots in subroutine names?**

I understand, that at least some of the respondents might feel like discouraging usage of autoloading, as well as trying to change what is a legal subroutine name, instead providing examples of better practices. I have nothing against these kinds of answers and don't consider them any less valuable. Still, please try to provide an answer to my original question as well.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, the end goal is a module, where, when an undefined subroutine is called, it is dynamically defined, based on its name. To implement this I mean to use AUTOLOAD, in a way similar to how it is used in [this tutorial](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/porm/ch11_04.htm).

Comment: your question and the answers have nothing to do with autoloading; maybe you mean something different by that than we expect?

Comment: your text seems to imply object methods, but your usage example is for a class method; can you clarify?

Comment: I've edited in some clarification about autoloading. I'm currently meaning to only call class methods and work with package variables. I don't really see any 'object' implications in my question, can you point to them?

Comment: "accessors" isn't usually a term used for class methods (at least in the perl OO world)

Comment: @ysth, Classes could have accessors to access class attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, that dot's are illegal in subroutine names. This has nothing to do with autoloading, they are just illegal. A dot is used for string concatenation, so your example of

```
MyModule->a.method.get
```

would actually be interpreted as

```
MyModule->a() . method() . get()
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is it possible to disable this concatenation, when calling a method of a specific Module?

Comment: There are ugly and depreciated tricks like source filters, but enforcing this kind of change of semantics just when calling a specific module will probably not work. Apart from that, use Perl as Perl and don't try to enforce the look and feel of other languages.

Comment: Not without forking perl off into a different interpreter and rewriting the specification.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, not and call them like ordinary methods [*].

Your choices are to abandon the . and use _ or something instead, or to not create accessor subs but instead have a generic get() function that takes an attribute name as a parameter.

( * Footnote: you can create such methods and call them indirectly, like so:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    no strict 'refs';
    *{'foo.bar'} = sub {
        use strict;
        return 'foo.bar value';
    }
}


package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $method = 'foo.bar';
my $value = Foo::->$method;
```

but that's going to cause way more headache than you want.)

Comment: The footnote implementation appears to work only if I know the method name beforehand. Is there a way to around this?

Comment: @Worse_Username, `AUTOLOAD`, but you obviously missed the point that `MyModule->do("a.method.get")` is much simpler.

Comment: @Worse_Username, `AUTOLOAD` or the rest?

Comment: @ikegami, I must've read the first half of your comment before you finished editing it. AUTOLOAD won't receive a subroutine that has dots in its name, that's the reason why I posted the question.

Comment: @Worse_Username, You are mistaken. `AUTOLOAD` doesn't care about the name at all. `perl -E"sub AUTOLOAD { say $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://r } my $method = 'a.b'; __PACKAGE__->$method();"` But like I said, the following is much simpler: `perl -E"sub do { say $_[1] } __PACKAGE__->do('a.b');"`

Comment: @Ikegami You could be right. I can't test it right now, but would the usage example I specified still work? Is assigning method name to a scalar string before calling it neccessary for AUTOLOAD to retrieve it correctly?

Comment: @Worse_Username, I was answering the new questions you asked in the comments. Re-asking your original question is not going to get you new answers, though.

Comment: @ikegami, sorry, I must've missed you comment in other place and answer. Now my sense of time continuity is completely confused. To confirm: AUTOLOAD won't receive the correct method name for the usage example in my question, correct?

Comment: "Is assigning method name to a scalar string before calling it necessary for AUTOLOAD..." no, it is necessary for calling it in the first place.  AUTOLOAD or not still has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: `AUTOLOAD` will receive the method name used, whatever it is. That would be `a` in your code. If the method called as a `.` in it, `AUTOLOAD` will receive it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to use Java (or whatever) syntax? In Perl, it's written `MyModule->a->get`. Use that.

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub AUTOLOAD {
   my $self = shift;

   my $name = our $AUTOLOAD =~ s/^.*:://r;
   my $path = ref($self) ? $self->{path}.".".$name : $name;

   if (is_path_method($path)) {
      return call_method($path);
   } else {
      return MyModule->___new(path => $path);
   }
}

sub ___new {
   my $class = shift;
   return bless({ @_ }, $class);
}

sub DESTROY { }
```

Note that this will fail if try to access a proxied `AUTOLOAD`, `can`, `DESTROY`, `DOES`, `import`, `isa`, `___new` or `VERSION`.

If you can have methods and attributes with the same name, use `MyModule->a->get->()`, which you can do by overloading `&{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Identifier-parsing, I don't see that 'mr.s' validates as an identifier under either utf8 or non-utf8 source parsing. Thus, it is not a valid subroutine name.